# Why is wpffontcache_v0400.exe hogging the CPU?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, wpf

In the last few days I've noticed really poor performance on a virtual machine I'm using at work. It's running **Windows Server 2003 SP 2**. When I check **Task Manager**, the process **wpffontcache_v0400.exe** is consuming almost all of the CPU.

What is **wpffontcache_v0400.exe** and how can I get it to not consume all of the CPU?

When I kill the process it starts up again straight away. Sometimes it resumes to normal CPU usage, other times it just jumps back to 100% usage no how many times I kill it.

Comment: Maybe this...http://www.spywareremovalhelp.org/spyware-removal-help/what-is-wpffontcache_v0400-exe-how-to-get-rid-of-wpffontcache_v0400-exe-virus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the font cache as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e2921a5b-2129-4360-a263-77114ef7fd48) by Jordan and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999756/what-is-the-use-of-wpffontcache-service-in-wpf-wpffontcache-v0400-exe-taking-10) by Cody seems to do the trick.